# XSL calculate sum of specific tag

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an example like:

```
<AgentInfo>
      <NumberOfAgent>
         <NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>24</NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>
         <DAY>2018-10-10T00:00:00+01:00</DAY>
         <SKILLSET_NAME>SOA</SKILLSET_NAME>
      </NumberOfAgent>
      <NumberOfAgent>
         <NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>3</NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>
         <DAY>2018-10-10T00:00:00+01:00</DAY>
         <SKILLSET_NAME>C#</SKILLSET_NAME>
      </NumberOfAgent>
      <NumberOfAgent>
         <NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>8</NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>
         <DAY>2018-10-10T00:00:00+01:00</DAY>
         <SKILLSET_NAME>Skillset2</SKILLSET_NAME>
      </NumberOfAgent>
      <NumberOfAgent>
         <NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>1</NUMBER_OF_AGENTS>
         <DAY>2018-10-11T00:00:00+01:00</DAY>
         <SKILLSET_NAME>Uninstalling Windows</SKILLSET_NAME>
      </NumberOfAgent>
   </AgentInfo>
```

i want to calculate sum of  value when dates  matched (values of same day)
for example : for day 2018-10-10 the sum will be 35.
i tried a lot without no luck.

Comment: Can you maybe share what you tried, and show where it goes wrong?

Comment: Did you accidentally post this twice (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947490/xsl-calculate-sum-of-specific-tag), or maybe there is an issue with SO duplicating questions....?

Comment: Answered this, maybe delete the other copy?

Comment: @TimC Yeah sorry i deleted the other one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group and sum values in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768712/how-to-group-and-sum-values-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to group the entries first by DAY and then sum within the groups. Try the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="AgentInfo">
    <AllUsers>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="NumberOfAgent" group-by="./DAY">
<group>
<count><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/NUMBER_OF_AGENTS)"/></count> 
<day><xsl:value-of select="DAY"/></day>
</group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </AllUsers>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks man! this answer helps me a lot with little changes according to my business case... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/AgentInfo/NumberOfAgent[DAY='2018-10-10T00:00:00+01:00']/NUMBER_OF_AGENTS)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```