# grouping based on the new value

Tags: xslt

I'm doing transform I want to add the values by the new site value. warehouse 150 and warehouse 120 becomes the US site and EU site only has warehouse 405. How do I do this?

input:

```
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse150</fld2>
    <fld3>13</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse120</fld2>
    <fld3>12</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>22</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>2</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse150</fld2>
    <fld3>7</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>6</fld3>
</Recordname>
```

output:

```
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <site>US</site>
    <fld3>25</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <site>EU</site>
    <fld3>24</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <site>US</site>
    <fld3>7</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <site>EU</site>
    <fld3>6</fld3>
</Recordname>
```

Looking forward to your answers as I am a newbie in **stylesheet**.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did try two step xslt as I don't know how to do it in just one. The first xslt will just susbtitute the fld2 to site warehouse150 orr warehouse120 becomes US and warehouse405 becomes EU and then the second xslt will just sum by site and by product. I'm hoping to have it in one xslt.

Comment: This is primarily a *grouping* problem (or at least so it seems). Grouping methods are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Which processor will you be using?

Comment: Right. I will be using XSLT 2.0 but my middleware can handle 1.0 as well. if it's easier in 2.0 then I'd rather do that

Comment: an example of group and sum is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768712/how-to-group-and-sum-values-in-xslt#2768949. If the example isn't clear can you edit your question? It should translate to your input

Comment: Thank you! I edited the title as grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Although it *is* possible to do this in a single pass, it is easier - and more readable - to do it in two: first rename the `fld2` element and populate it with your site names, then group the result by product and site:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform (for all modes) -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
     <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="first-pass"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- group by product and site -->
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$first-pass/Recordname" group-by="concat(fld1, '|', site)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="output"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename and repopulate fld2 -->
<xsl:template match="fld2" mode="first-pass">
    <site>
        <xsl:value-of select="if(.='warehouse405') then 'EU' else 'US'"/>
    </site>
</xsl:template>

<!-- sum current group -->
<xsl:template match="fld3" mode="output">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/fld3)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6F/1

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need a root element in your XML, like this

```
<records>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse150</fld2>
    <fld3>13</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse120</fld2>
    <fld3>12</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>22</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product1</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>2</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse150</fld2>
    <fld3>7</fld3>
</Recordname>
<Recordname>
    <fld1>product2</fld1>
    <fld2>warehouse405</fld2>
    <fld3>6</fld3>
</Recordname>
</records>
```

A simple way using XSLT for your case is to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <records>
            <xsl:for-each select="records/Recordname">
            <!-- sort the nodes-->
                <xsl:sort select="fld1" />
                <xsl:variable name="ffld1"><xsl:value-of select="fld1" /></xsl:variable>
                
                <!-- for each each product -->
                <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[fld1=$ffld1])=0">
                    <!-- output US record -->
                    <Recordname>
                        <fld1><xsl:value-of select="$ffld1" /></fld1>
                        <fld2>US</fld2>
                        <fld3><xsl:value-of select="sum(//Recordname[fld1=$ffld1 and (fld2='warehouse150' or fld2='warehouse120')]/fld3)" /></fld3>
                    </Recordname>
                    <Recordname>
                    <!-- output EU record -->
                        <fld1><xsl:value-of select="$ffld1" /></fld1>
                        <fld2>EU</fld2>
                        <fld3><xsl:value-of select="sum(//Recordname[fld1=$ffld1 and (fld2='warehouse405')]/fld3)" /></fld3>
                    </Recordname>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </records>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above gets the output you want, though its not as elegant as the Muenchian method (nothing ever is).

See [How to group and sum values in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768712/how-to-group-and-sum-values-in-xslt#2768949)

Comment: If Muenchian grouping is best, why post an inferior solution? And why use XSLT 1.0 methods when OP can use XSLT 2.0? Also you are assuming that every product exists in both sites.

Comment: XSLT1 is always available, so why not? Muenchian is more elegant (subjective), but may not be as easily understood (also subjective). Posting an alternative may be instructive.

Comment: Muenchian grouping is more efficient - objectively. You don't know how many records OP has. And of course XSLT 2.0 grouping method is preferable  - otherwise why would they add it?

Comment: Thank you i got it working but I'm having problem with namespace